# MySQL: How to get not repeated values?

Tags: mysql

There is  MySQL table:

```
col1   col2
1       a 
1       b
2       c
2       d
```

The wished result as:

```
  col1    col2  col3 
    1        a      b 
    2        c      d
```

I did :

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2 , t2.col2 from
my_table t1 left join my_table t2  
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where t1.col2 <> t2.col2
```

But i get 4 rows

```
col1   col2  col3
1       b     a
1       a     b
2       c     d
2       d     c
```

Comment: Will there always only be 2 rows for col 1?  if not this is a Pivot. and there's several examples on this on stack already.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not have completely duplicate rows, just change your where clause to `where t1.col2 < t2.col2`.

This will make sure that you can get

```
1 a b
```

but you will not get

```
1 b a
```

row.